# Azure API Management developer portal - Customise menu and reports

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm wondering if it is possible to customise the developer portal menu.  In a dev environment I don't need to worry about people signing up or logging in so it is possible to remove completely the Authenticated and Anonymous menus?

[image]

Also is it possible to customise the reports page and use some reports generated from App Insights queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is possible to remove completely the Authenticated and Anonymous menus?

**Yes, you can achieve it**. Go to the developer portal, click `Anonymous user menu` and choose `delete navigation item` and then press the `Save` button in the menu at the bottom.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize) to learn how to customize developer portal.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see that! Cheers